# How do I re-position an axes for a re-positioned bar chart mark?

Tags: vega-lite, vega, vegas-viz, vega-embed, vega-lite-api

I need to create a visualization that contains multiple marks, namely 2 bar charts side by side.  I need them to be in the same vega spec, not 2 separate vega specs.

After much research and a decent amount of trial and error, I discovered you can move the chart into position by setting the "range" property of the scales, but this moves only the chart series objects (i.e. the bars) but not the Axes.  The Axes for some reason stay stuck to the far edges of the visualization canvas.  How can I get them to move with the visualization?

I tried placing the chart into a "Group" mark, as the description suggested this would act as a separate Vega spec, however the contained bar chart wasn't contained at all as the axes continued to sit on the outer edges of the root parent.

Is this a bug or am I going about this the wrong way?

This is how it looks:
[image: How it looks]

This is what I need it to look like:
[image: What I need]

The following is an example Vega spec showing the behavior described:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "A basic bar chart example, with value labels shown upon mouse hover.",
  "width": 700,
  "height": 500,
  "autosize": "pad",

  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "values": [
        {"category": "A", "amount": 28},
        {"category": "B", "amount": 55},
        {"category": "C", "amount": 43},
        {"category": "D", "amount": 91},
        {"category": "E", "amount": 81},
        {"category": "F", "amount": 53},
        {"category": "G", "amount": 19},
        {"category": "H", "amount": 87}
      ]
    }
  ],

  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "tooltip",
      "value": {},
      "on": [
        {"events": "rect:mouseover", "update": "datum"},
        {"events": "rect:mouseout",  "update": "{}"}
      ]
    }
  ],

  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "xscale",
      "type": "band",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "category"},
      "range": [400 , 800],
      "padding": 0.05,
      "round": true
    },
    {
      "name": "yscale",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "amount"},
      "nice": true,
      "range": [300 , 100]
    }
  ],

  "axes": [
    { "orient": "bottom", "scale": "xscale" },
    { "orient": "left", "scale": "yscale" }
  ],

  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data":"table"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"scale": "xscale", "field": "category"},
          "width": {"scale": "xscale", "band": 1},
          "y": {"scale": "yscale", "field": "amount"},
          "y2": {"scale": "yscale", "value": 0}
        },
        "update": {
          "fill": {"value": "steelblue"}
        },
        "hover": {
          "fill": {"value": "red"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "align": {"value": "center"},
          "baseline": {"value": "bottom"},
          "fill": {"value": "#333"}
        },
        "update": {
          "x": {"scale": "xscale", "signal": "tooltip.category", "band": 0.5},
          "y": {"scale": "yscale", "signal": "tooltip.amount", "offset": -2},
          "text": {"signal": "tooltip.amount"},
          "fillOpacity": [
            {"test": "datum === tooltip", "value": 0},
            {"value": 1}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve. What does your end goal look like?

Comment: Thanks for replying.  Have added screenshots as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Use the padding property. Don't forget to close the github issue if this is what you want.

[Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhAATONABONHJnaT0AQQAETJBBpRdSRdtgnM2uAA8kCHABs4U7QHc6MbcSQOGcbQ5ITHAOENoQMGyu4toMOBLaCGwMEP6RpIqU0iDusvRoACwADEUy8DRkWGgATCUyOEiysjTiZGigTgBmmIV1IJhsOGgCpSDKlT2oAjJMbNhsCMMAvjKySJgoqADaoOJ2cGj9QU7Z3r4KaDsgUOvkbIoAnoea2XbJ4pPVABwroDeYd0ehwAQq8kgwPsMBL9rrcyPcnugAMJg96TAoAZhh-0BiJAABFURDJgBOACM2LhCMOAFEiZDUF8KVI-lSgegAGL0yYCLEs2EA+HskAAcW5aDJJMpgup6AAEuLGQB2JYAXTVMgMZD2oUuu32hwGbAcaiGMjOfnaKxAEj1IDgpA+EEOijgUEwqHBqTYGWycTWAMOAYYixhDrgTpdbo9XrgyR6Mn9t0OwCWIDVGpA0B8F22+oQB3Q1mzJxkmAeOELID04lk2VkCyQLXacnWmyOTFLIE6NBCdfQOKFT2tiiQrSruXy9UazVaaCKlCK0zG737mEUfhhewLhweJYOq0bzdQoAD7Y2nYP3d7Dn7IDexPTMnEhkL678MlH48O5Qm6dVMhINYuZXPcvYMtWcwDIsmo3CcRb7k+oBgRGkwgF0CZZnBVZ7th-4yMgigANbOnm-QVlWrrutknSKAsLZnoaxwHNaEZQGw8gtqhcCKC21gtohCF4TIPZ9ocg7Utak4wAJeFCTm2Q1v2zIgIioCCapiEiTed4PpC1oPNUskKeguEKeaPiWqgRRLNaSaBie14OA4LYWlWEAAiEnaWrZZQ+jxLY9s5rmWZRcB1rZvmgOWlaGjYmFsRxhagNxvGOT4FQaKAbnialT7VvoIQtMlIA5egszzKG2nBY5ZUgAAxBiTXpnZOABiV-GORpxbCVmmU+IabDGqalASUCMxjv2C7QjIalYSZmm9VqOqDcNKiUHpmFsJ0nSpJMAC01TWgC1iTOp-UuegRomutm35UFDgAPINFAdCIlcAIeUG6whtoAC8APaNdpqnKF84wmVFLqrZ6pAA)

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "A basic bar chart example, with value labels shown upon mouse hover.",
  "width": 400,
  "height": 200,
  "padding": {"left": 400, "top": 50, "right": 5, "bottom": 5}, 

  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "values": [
        {"category": "A", "amount": 28},
        {"category": "B", "amount": 55},
        {"category": "C", "amount": 43},
        {"category": "D", "amount": 91},
        {"category": "E", "amount": 81},
        {"category": "F", "amount": 53},
        {"category": "G", "amount": 19},
        {"category": "H", "amount": 87}
      ]
    }
  ],

  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "tooltip",
      "value": {},
      "on": [
        {"events": "rect:mouseover", "update": "datum"},
        {"events": "rect:mouseout",  "update": "{}"}
      ]
    }
  ],

  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "xscale",
      "type": "band",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "category"},
      "range": "width",
      "padding": 0.05,
      "round": true
    },
    {
      "name": "yscale",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "amount"},
      "nice": true,
      "range": "height"
    }
  ],

  "axes": [
    { "orient": "bottom", "scale": "xscale" },
    { "orient": "left", "scale": "yscale" }
  ],

  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data":"table"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"scale": "xscale", "field": "category"},
          "width": {"scale": "xscale", "band": 1},
          "y": {"scale": "yscale", "field": "amount"},
          "y2": {"scale": "yscale", "value": 0}
        },
        "update": {
          "fill": {"value": "steelblue"}
        },
        "hover": {
          "fill": {"value": "red"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "align": {"value": "center"},
          "baseline": {"value": "bottom"},
          "fill": {"value": "#333"}
        },
        "update": {
          "x": {"scale": "xscale", "signal": "tooltip.category", "band": 0.5},
          "y": {"scale": "yscale", "signal": "tooltip.amount", "offset": -2},
          "text": {"signal": "tooltip.amount"},
          "fillOpacity": [
            {"test": "datum === tooltip", "value": 0},
            {"value": 1}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```